# R-4.0.1 Not sure I understand this message: Warning message: In proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output

Tags: r, proj, extract, stack

Context: I want to store the TIFF data to use it for running a linear regression model later on.
Ultimate goal: Create a carbon map using field data as a basis.

Libraries:

```r
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)

plotcoord <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(AGCplot[,3:4], AGCplot[,1:2],proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat')) 
pspcoord<-spTransform(plotcoord, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=21')) #Omzetten naar UTM21N (= S1)
plot(pspcoord)

s1 <- stack('Some.tif')

colnamen = c("plotid","AGC","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B8A","B11","B12","NDVI","NDWI","MMRI","IRECI","MASI","VV","VH")

s1_e <- extract(s1,pspcoord,method='bilinear')
```

Upon extraction I get the following message:

```
Warning message:
In proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? We can't run this without your data or something similar, there's some odd triple-backticks in there, and you don't use half the packages you load with `library`. The more minimal code you can use to illustrate the problem, the more people will help.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.4-2/topics/CRS-class I think gives some background

Comment: see also http://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/PROJ6_GDAL3.html

Comment: Also show the versions of packages loaded, and any output that is printed. `library(rgdal)` will show the GDAL and PROJ version numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not related to R 4.0.1 but to `rgdal 1.5-8` and the [migration to `gdal 3` and `proj 6`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html). This is a very long and complex process that impact hundreds maybe thouthands of packages. All the packages are not yet up-to-date with what is coming.

You can have a look to `?rgdal::set_thin_PROJ6_warnings()` to eliminate those warnings.

**Edit after Roger's comment:** See also

- https://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html
- https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html

Comment: Please refer to https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html and https://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html to understand that everybody needs to understand that proper representation of coordinate reference systems matters crucially for all spatial work, unless you will never need accuracy of greater than a degree. Relating one data source to another means that all should be registered correctly. The warnings are indicating that your work may  be affected by the change introduced with PROJ 6 (and GDAL 3), adopted by R-spatial and rspatial.