# sp::proj4string equivalent in the PROJ6 framework?

Tags: gdal, r, proj, sp, rgdal

I am confused about the [shift from PROJ4 to PROJ6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html) in the (relatively) recent versions of the spatial packages of R (and gdal for that matter). I used to use `sp::proj4string()` to get the projection code / CRS argument from an `sp` object and use that code further in my scripts. Now I get a warning (which tells me that my [projection might be inaccurate](https://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html)). I am obviously doing something wrong. Which function should I use to get the projection code without a warning? I would personally prefer the EPSG code if that level of simplicity was possible...

```r
library(sp)

x <- SpatialPolygons(
            list(Polygons(
                 list(Polygon(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,1), c(3,8,10,12,3)))), 
                 ID = 1)), 
            proj4string = CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326"))

proj4string(x)
#> Warning in proj4string(x): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See also the references and comments in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364667/r-4-0-1-not-sure-i-understand-this-message-warning-message-in-proj4stringx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also quite confused about the move away from PROJ Strings and what to use instead until I watched [this](https://media.ccc.de/v/bucharest-198-revamp-of-coordinate-reference-system-management-in-the-osgeo-c-c-stack-with-proj-and-gdal/playlist) video of a talk held last year at FOSS4G.

Here's my main takeaways:

### Why PROJ and GDAL are moving away from PROJ-strings

With PROJ4 every transformation is done using the "hub-approach". So everything will first be converted to WGS84 and only then transformed to the target projection.

This approach can lead to larger errors in the transformation process than direct transformation between the two projections. At the worst case the needed transformation isn't even possible with this approach.
Since PROJ strings can be ambiguous, direct transformations are often not possible.

An example from the talk:

The old Australian datum GDA94 and the new GDA2020 are both based on WGS84. However one is using the reference frame ITRF2014 at Epoch 2020.0 and the other ITRF92 at Epoch 1994.0. Those differences can't be captured in a PROJ-string (as far as I understood) and thus all projections have the almost exact same PROJ String as WGS84. Converting between both with the hub-approach would lead to no change in the coordinates. While actually Australia has moved 1.8 meters between 1994 and 2020 and the datum conversion should reflect that.

With a direct transformation erros like that would not happen.

### What you should use instead

Instead you should ideally use non-ambiguous definitions for projections like EPSG Codes or definitions in WKT2 Format.

However if you do not intend to do datum transformations (or then don't care about a few meters or more of inaccuracy) you can still use PROJ-Strings, but do be aware that best-practice is to use EPSG Codes or WKT2.

### How is this implemented in sp

**[Check out Mikko's answer below for a more up to date workflow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397927/157379)**

`CRS`-objects in sp now have an additional field `comment` in which a WKT2 representation of the CRS is saved.

So the best practice workflow with `sp` now looks like this (taken and expanded a bit from [here](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html#crs-objects-in-sp)):

```
# Define the CRS using an EPSG Code
x <- CRS(SRS_string='EPSG:4326')

# Display the stored CRS using comment()
cat(comment(x), "\n")

# Store the wkt in a variable
wkt <- comment(x)

# Use this to assign the CRS of another sp-object
y <- CRS(SRS_string = wkt)
```

All in all `sf` has a lot more convenient functions for accessing and handling crs than `sp`. You can read more about how `sf` handles it in the same link given above.

Comment: `x$proj4string` seems to return the comments, while `sp::proj4string(x)` does not. Perhaps this is a bug, which will be fixed in future versions of the `sp` package. Perhaps it is intended. Hard to say. I'll accept this answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

Proj4strings are being phased out. Thanks to the sf package and its developers there is a simple trick for converting a proj4string to the WKT format.

Just ignore the datum warnings coming from rgdal and, in fact, you can just turn them off because they do become irksome. Either add `options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none")` to your Rprofile.site file or issue it before adding any libraries.

For example with the geographic WGS84 projection, using `sf::st_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")` will result in

```
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["unknown",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8901]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

From the [R-spatial blog **R spatial follows GDAL and PROJ development**](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html) sf developers state:

> Use of so-called PROJ4-strings (like +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84) are
> discouraged, they no longer offer sufficient description of coordinate
> reference systems; use of +init=epsg:XXXX leads to warnings

Comment: "EPSG format is dead" ... this fills me with a certain dread, will there be no easy shortcut for projections or we have to keep WKT snippets around? Can you suggest some reading / background links about this?

Comment: EPSG codes are valid in the EPSG:<code> format and are supported by PROJ. The +init=epsg:<code> format however is deprecated. For information about he best format to store your spatial reference: https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand, a reason to use `sf::st_crs()` over `sp::CRS(SRS_string = ...)` would be that the former does not return warnings. It seems that transfer process is still unfinished in `rgdal` and `sp` packages. I'll try setting the options in the .onLoad function of my package and see whether that passes CRAN checks.

Comment: Unless I have really misunderstood something about PROJ6 "EPSG format is dead" is phrased quite badly. As far as I have understood it, in PROJ6 either WKT or EPSG (or other codes) should be used. So everything which isn't ambiguous like a PROJ4 string.

Comment: If the problem is in getting the EPSG code so isn't it available in WKT2 as ID at GEOGCRS or PROJCRS level? For example `projinfo epsg:4326
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs

WKT2_2018 string:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
      ...  
    ID["EPSG",4326]]`.

Comment: fyi https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2019-October/050983.html

Comment: @JonasV, please see my edit. In R "use of EPSG codes will lead to errors"! I would not say that the format is dead is phrased quite badly but, perhaps at the moment not quite the case. However, going forward I imagine that at some point EPSG will cease working in R.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans yes definitely, in a proj string they will also die at some point. However using EPSG Codes as is (i.e. EPSG:4326) is right now expected to keep working for a long time. I am not sure how easily you can use EPSG codes in sp though. In sf this for sure isn't a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answers. Is there a function that replaces `sp::proj4string` to obtain PROJ information from an object as shown in the example?

Comment: @Mikko I have added a short code sample to my answer how a "best-practice" workflow could look like using `sp`

Answer (score 1):

That warning doesn't affect your output at all. As the other folks suggested, sf package can be useful for cleaner and simple EPSG coding. Here is your code adapted:

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
coords <- list(rbind(c(1,3), c(2,8), c(3,10), c(4,12), c(1,3)))
x2 <- st_sf(st_geometry(st_polygon(x = coords)), crs="EPSG:4326")
x2$ID <- 1
mapview(x2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this as an answer (was originally meant as a comment). Perhaps it helps someone since there is and has been a lot of confusion about this. It expands the answers above. There is [another helpful question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727886/proj4-to-proj6-upgrade-and-discarded-datum-warnings).

In short, to print the wkt comment and avoid the warnings with PROJ6 CRS objects, use `sp::wkt` instead of `sp::proj4string`:

```
sp::wkt(x)
[1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"
```

To assign a CRS to a SpatialPolygons object, which does not have a CRS, use the `sp::proj4string` function even though you are assigning wkt (= well-known text, PROJ6 CRS format). Note how you can now omit the `SRS_string` argument within `sp::CRS()`.

```r
library(sp)

x <- SpatialPolygons(
  list(Polygons(
    list(Polygon(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,1), c(3,8,10,12,3)))), 
    ID = 1))
)

proj4string(x) <- CRS("EPSG:4326")

proj4string(x) # print the PROJ4 string
#> Warning in proj4string(x): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

wkt(x) # print the PROJ6 wkt comment
#> [1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"
```

To borrow the PROJ6 from another SpatialPolygons object, you can either use only `proj4string` or use *the combination* of `proj4string` and `wkt`:

```r
y <- SpatialPolygons(
  list(Polygons(
    list(Polygon(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,1), c(3,8,10,12,3)))), 
    ID = 1))
)

proj4string(y) <- proj4string(x) # proj4string(y) <- wkt(x) would also work
# but wkt(y) <- wkt(x) would not because wkt() has no assingment.
# proj4string(y) <- CRS(wkt(x)) also works as shown by JonasV

proj4string(y)
#> Warning in proj4string(y): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

wkt(y)
#> [1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"
```

The `sp::proj4string()` should be understood as a function name. It does not necessarily have to do with PROJ4 any longer if it is used in the assignment. The good news is that you only need to change the "inside" from "+init=epsg:4326" to "EPSG:4326" in the `sp::CRS()` function and things should work as previously as long as you do not use the `sp::proj4string()` function to retrieve PROJ6 (wkt) information. If you do, you'll get a warning, but the comment is actually not lost anyway in the assignment (as demonstrated by the `proj4string(y) <- proj4string(x)` example). It is only lost if you use `proj4string()` to print CRS information:

```r
comment(proj4string(x))
#> NULL
```

**EDIT:** What if you want both, the string and comment? Use `raster::crs()`. This can be useful to keep it PROJ6 through a function/script.

```r
raster::crs(x)
#> CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 

comment(raster::crs(x))
[1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>