# R 4.0.4 Raster package treating Albers as unknown projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I'm running a fresh R installation with RStudio. Installed packages are:

```
library(randomForest)
library(randomForestExplainer)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
```

When I try loading any raster with **South America Albers Equal Area Conic projection (ESPG: 102033)** I receive the following warning:

> Warning message:
> In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
> Discarded datum Unknown based on Australian Natl & S. Amer. 1969 ellipsoid in Proj4 definition

Keeping the projection is important to me, cause I need to be able to collect point samples from that raster and I need to make sure the points and rasters are projected in the same coordinate system. Albers seems to be the most accurate for my study area.

I have packages updated to the last version availble @ cran and I cannot seem to find a solution for this.

Projection details are (quoting QGIS 3.4.4 defs):

> Extent: Extent not known
> Proj4: +proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs

I need a way to import rasters with albers projections without having them discarded.

Comment: No error there, only a warning. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364667/r-4-0-1-not-sure-i-understand-this-message-warning-message-in-proj4stringx/364671#364671 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372692/how-should-i-handle-crs-properly-after-the-major-change-in-proj-library/373449#373449

Comment: 102033 is an ESRI projection code, not an EPSG one. The warning looks like the CRS has an ellipsoid but no datum definition, and PROJ is loathe to assume a datum. The unofficial epsg.io site has an entry ESRI:102033 which gives a datum that text-matches to two possible datums in the official epsg.org registry. Even so its possible your PROJ doesn't have datum info for those datum codes. Can you supply a raster with the coordinate info? (one with all zeroes as content will do if the data is confidential)

Comment: @JRR you are right, I'm not receiving an error, it's only a warning. Theoretically, I could still run my code, but there will be a point in my workflow where i'll need to point-sample my rasters with a point shapefile and I need to ensure that everything has a coordinate so the dots fall in the right place. It seems like a warning serious enough to me. Is it possible I'm overreacting?

Comment: @Spacedman Weird. I did see 102033 being called both ESRI and ESPG projections and to be honest, I was a little unsure which one was right. QGIS says it's an ESPG code (https://imgur.com/a/dW0YmyY). As for the raster, you can find it here. Link will last 7 days: https://we.tl/t-bj1j6Lb8k6